# Detecting non european characters

Tags: javascript, regex, latin

I need to prevent my users from entering non-european characters in a text box.

For example, here's how I disallow Cyrillic:

```
$('.test').keyup(function(e) {
        var toTest = $(this).val();
        var rforeign = /[\u0400-\u04FF]/i;
        if (rforeign.test(toTest)) {
            alert("No cyrillic allowed");
            $(this).val('');
        } 
    });
```

But I also need to exclude Arabic, Japanese, and so on.

I just want to allow:

- ASCII English, standard characters
- Italian accented letters: à è ì ò ù á é í ó ú
- other special characters from European languages: French, German...

Is there a way to do that with ranges?

I tried `/[\u0400-\u04FF]/i` but it just allows ASCII English (not Italian for example).

Comment: I think you need to define "Europe". Cyrillic scripts are used in a handful of European countries, so where exactly are you drawing the line? Do you consider Iceland to be a part of Europe?

Comment: What about Arabic numerals...? There are several on this very page...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just allow unicode symbols in some given ranges, e.g.

```
/^[a-z\u00C0-\u00F6\u00F8-\u017E]+$/i
```

Example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4y6e6bj5/3/

---

This regular expression allows basic latin / latin extended A (diacritics and accented letters). It excludes any other alphabet/symbol.

If you need to allow other specific unicode symbols, look at the [unicode table](http://unicode-table.com/) and insert as many ranges as you need into the regular expression

Comment: While this work perfectly, it does not detect non european characters as much as detect non-non european characters.

Comment: this is not working... I replaced your regex in my code and still am able to type ية or Ф without any alert!

Comment: ok thank you, I just needed to check the negative match, it works. 
what if I need to allow punctuation and white spaces too?

Comment: as you can see from the unicode table I've linked punctuation is in unicode range `\u0020-\002F`. Include it in the regexp.

Comment: I had XML containing a bunch of bidirectional characters (Arabic and Hebrew), as well as Tamil characters, produced in error via OCR. I found them using [\u0590-\u1000].

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative set :

```
[^A-Za-zàèìòùáéíóú(othercharacters..)]
```